# Major product of the nitration of benz[cd]indol-2(1H)-one

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

> Decide major product for given reaction of electrophilic aromatic substitution:
>
> [image: Nitration of benz[cd]indol-2(1H)-one (CAS 130‐00‐7)]

Is the major product **a** because of steric hindrance, or is it **b** because of hydrogen bonding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this patent [here](https://www.iprdb.com/patent-2182-US3950347A.html), N-ethyl 1,8-naphtholactam nitrates in the 4 position i.e. structure **a**. It seems entirely likely the N-unsubstituted material will do likewise.

Comment: I Got the answer but I didn't understood "It seems entirely likely the N-unsubstituted material will do likewise." Meaning

Comment: Meaning I cannot find a reference to the nitration of  1,8-naphtholactam so I've quoted the nearest example. In my opinion 1,8-naphtholactam will also nitrate in the same position.

Comment: @Waylander Is iprdb.com a reliable source from your experience? Don't you think a conventional link to [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3950347A/en) (which they seem to copy content from without any quality control) would be better?

Comment: The reference is what Google found for me. It references the US patent so in this case it seems reliable. The result is in accord with my expectations